# How to find words at a specific place inside the given string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, slice

I need to extract the words inside `(` `)` for a perticular catagory.

I need to find the words inside `(` `)` in
`Technology (Pyrolysis, Gasification)`

Also the same for words inside `(` `)` in
`Application (Agriculture, Animal Feed, Health & Beauty Products)`

This is my string:
`string = ''' U.S. Biochar Market Size, Share & Trends Analysis Report By Technology (Pyrolysis, Gasification), By Application (Agriculture, Animal Feed, Health & Beauty Products), By State, And Segment Forecasts'''`

I've written the function but it's not working for all instance for some instance its also fetching
`By state, and segment forecast` which is not needed.

---

Eg.

Application = 'Agriculture, Animal Feed, Health & Beauty Products'

Technology = 'Pyrolysis, Gasification'

For a large data set of similar sentences using python programming.

```
enter code here def check_para(args):
s = args
start = s.find('Technology (')
end = s.find('),', start)
techno = s[start:end][len('Technology ('):]

s = args
start = s.find('Material (')
end = s.find('),', start)
mat = s[start:end][len('Material ('):]

s = args
start = s.find('Product (')
end = s.find('),', start)
prod = s[start:end][len('Product ('):]

s = args
start = s.find('Service (')
end = s.find('),', start)
serv = s[start:end][len('Service ('):]

s = args
start = s.find('Type (')
end = s.find('),', start)
typ = s[start:end][len('Type ('):]

s = args
start = s.find('Form (')
end = s.find('),', start)
form = s[start:end][len('Form ('):]

s = args
start = s.find('Application (')
end = s.find('),', start)
appli = s[start:end][len('Application ('):]

s = args
start = s.find('End Use (')
end = s.find('),', start)
enduse = s[start:end][len('End Use ('):]

s = args
start = s.find('Derivative Grades (')
end = s.find('),', start)
deriv = s[start:end][len('Derivative Grades ('):]

type1 = deriv + form + typ + serv + prod + techno + mat

application = appli + enduse

if len(application) > 0 :
    application = application.replace(', ', '\n')
else:
    application = 'Application I\nApplication II\nApplication III\n'

if len(type1) > 0:
    type1 = type1.replace(', ', '\n')
else:
    type1 = 'Type I\nTypeII\nType III\n'

return application, type1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.findall` we can try:

```py
string = ''' U.S. Biochar Market Size, Share & Trends Analysis Report By Technology (Pyrolysis, Gasification), By Application (Agriculture, Animal Feed, Health & Beauty Products), By State, And Segment Forecasts'''
matches = re.findall(r'(\w+) \((.*?)\)', string)
for match in matches:
    print(match[0] + ' = ' + "'" + match[1] + "'")
```

This prints:

```
Technology = 'Pyrolysis, Gasification'
Application = 'Agriculture, Animal Feed, Health & Beauty Products'
```